# gradle 2.2.2 ,android studio,No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.call() is applicable for argument types:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, groovy

I have import a project form eclipse to android studio , I meet this proplem
,android studio 2.2.2, gradle 2.2.2.

> Error:(6, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project
> ':projectName'.
>
> No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.call() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
>
> Possible solutions: wError:(6, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':projectName'.
>
> No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.call() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
>
> Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), and(java.lang.Boolean)ait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), and(java.lang.Boolean)

project gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    enforceUniquePackageName = false

    aaptOptions{
        cruncherEnabled = false
        useNewCruncher = false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zl.activity"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile project(':someLib')
     compile files('libs/Authentication_agent32.jar')
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's an error in your gradle script. You don't show your gradle script, so there's no way of guessing where

Comment: @tim_yates Here is the gradle file

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.It caused by 9-patch ,just fix the pic ,Everything is OK now.